# Flex XMLListCollection sort on nested tags

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a requirement of sorting the `<ename>` in the XML with in the branch. The XML goes like this:

```
<company>
  <branch>
    <name>finance</name>
    <emp>
      <ename>rahul</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
    <emp>
      <ename>sunil</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
    <emp>
      <ename>akash</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
    <emp>
      <ename>alok</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
  </branch>
  <branch>
    <name>finance</name>
    <emp>
      <ename>sameer</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
    <emp>
      <ename>rahul</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
    <emp>
      <ename>anand</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
    <emp>
      <ename>sandeep</ename>
      <phno>123456</phno>
    </emp>
  </branch>
</company>
```

I tried it with taking XML in `XMLList`:

```
var xl:XMLList = new XMLList(branch.ename) 
var xlc:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xl);
```

then applied sort to the `<ename>`. I am able to get the sorted but `XMLListCollection` but the problem is I got the `<ename>` collection sorted but I need the sorted `<ename>` in the XML.

I tried with deleting the the item in Collection then adding the sorted list but in that case the `<name>` is lost.

Please help me out in sorting `<ename>` or is there any way to specify nested tags in `SortField` name? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check my previous question that is pretty much the same out [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869964/flex-newbie-xmllist-question-sorting-xml-and-xmllist).

Look for the answer I provided, I was able to sort the XML directly without having to use XML list collection